# Newtonsoft.Json: десериализация массива разнотипных объектов

Tags: c#, json

Подскажите, каким образом можно выполнить десереализацию массива объектов (классов/структур), которые имеют разный тип. Например:

```
{"response":[{"name":"", "password":"", "information":""}, {"data":"", "tables":"", "rows":"", "colums":""}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужен [`CustomCreationConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_CustomCreationConverter_1.htm).